# How can I cat back exact formatting regardless of shell?

Tags: ssh, sh, zsh, cat

While trying to write a script, I found an interesting issue with `cat` today.  If I do the following at the command line, everything works properly:

```
var=$(ssh user@server "cat /directory/myfile.sh")
echo $var > ~/newfile.sh
```

This works and I have a script file with all the proper formatting and can run it.  However, if I do the EXACT same thing in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

var=$(ssh user@server "cat /directory/myfile.sh")
echo $var > ~/newfile.sh
```

The file is mangled with carriage returns and weird formatting.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  My goal is to ultimately cat a script from a server and run it locally on my machine.

**EDIT**

I now know that this is happening because of my invoking `#!/bin/sh` in my shell script.  The command line works because I'm using `zsh` and it is preserving the formatting.

Is there a way to cat back the results regardless of the shell?

Comment: `/bin/sh` might be a different shell than the one you're running. In particular, on Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint), `/bin/sh` is the Debian Almquist Shell dash, not bash.

Comment: @larsmans interesting... my native shell is `zsh` so do you think that could be the reason for the varying results?

Comment: I've never used Zsh, but that's still my best guess. Check if `echo` is built-into Zsh.

Comment: @larsmans it was in fact the difference in shells.  If I change my shell to `bash` or `sh` I get the issues with formatting and since my shell was using `#!/bin/sh` it was throwing off the formatting.  Is there any way to echo back the exact format of a file regardless of the shell being used?

Comment: Try replacing `echo` with `/bin/echo`.

Comment: If it works with `zsh`, use `/bin/zsh` in the shebang line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to have figured out, word splitting is off by default on zsh, but on in `sh`, `bash`, etc. You can prevent word splitting in all shells by quoting the variable:

```
echo "$var" > ~/newfile.sh
```

Note that `echo` appends a newline to its output by default, which you can suppress (on most `echo` implementations and builtins) with `-n`.